# how to make ajax javascript work on press of enter key

Tags: php, javascript, forms, jquery, keypress

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='search_user_submit']").click(function() {
        var cv = $('#newInput').val();
        var cvtwo = $('input[name="search_option"]:checked').val();
        var data = { "cv" : cv, "cvtwo" : cvtwo }; // sending two variables
        $("#SR").html('<img src="loading.gif"/>').show();
        var url = "user.php";
        $.post(url, data, function(data) {
            $("#SR").html(data).show();
        });

    });
});
});//]]>  
</script>
```

This works fine when i hit the button, but when i press enter key all the variables and its values get shown in the address bar.

So how can i add a keypress event for this purpose:-

I have tried this code for keypress still its not working:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
    function Script(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
             var cv = $('#newInput').val();
            var cvtwo = $('input[name="search_option"]:checked').val();
            var data = { "cv" : cv, "cvtwo" : cvtwo }; // sending two variables
            $("#SR").html('<img src="loading.gif"/>').show();
            var url = "user.php";
            $.post(url, data, function(data) {
                $("#SR").html(data).show();
            });
        }
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Also for the keypress i am creating the textbox on a click of option button and in my javascript i have specified this:-

`input.onkeypress = 'return Script(event)';`

Comment: Is there an enclosing form that is getting submitted? Also, you should do a `return false` from your event handler

Answer (score 2):

You should be using forms, and having a `onsubmit` event rather than handling the enter key.

```
<form id="myform">
    <!-- ... -->
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit = function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // ...
}
</script>
```

No error checking done, but hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I thin you want to execute ajax call and tiger the button on enter

try this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='search_user_submit']").keyup(function(event){

    if(event.keyCode == 13)
{


        var cv = $('#newInput').val();
        var cvtwo = $('input[name="search_option"]:checked').val();
        var data = { "cv" : cv, "cvtwo" : cvtwo }; // sending two variables
        $("#SR").html('<img src="loading.gif"/>').show();
        var url = "user.php";
        $.post(url, data, function(data) {
            $("#SR").html(data).show();
}
        });

    });
});
});//]]>  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I think hitting enter is sending the form to the browser, and it must be a form with the action set to GET (or nothing, which default to GET). This causes the browser to refresh and the form variables appear in the URL as a query string. The browser refresh prevents your script from really being executed (or it's being executed as the page reloads, so you don't see it).

If you do `e.preventDefault()` if the `Script()`, that will prevent that default action from occurring.

[edit] Gopal just beat me to giving pretty much the same answer.

I do want to add that jQuery handles event binding and stuff and maybe for a better flow, you can replace `function Script(e)` with

```
$('input').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var cv = $('#newInput').val();
        var cvtwo = $('input[name="search_option"]:checked').val();
        var data = { "cv" : cv, "cvtwo" : cvtwo }; // sending two variables
        $("#SR").html('<img src="loading.gif"/>').show();
        var url = "user.php";
        $.post(url, data, function(data) {
            $("#SR").html(data).show();
        });
    }
});
```

and then you don't need `input.onkeypress = 'return Script(event)';` anywhere. jQuery has a function like `.keypress()` (see [jQuery's keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)) for pretty much any event, and you can even use `.bind()` for binding multiple events. Refer to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to learn more.